# How to get a Key&value from result-set(as individually) From Object

Tags: rest, spring-boot, plsql

```
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate);
simpleJdbcCall.withProcedureName("getMultipleResultsetProc");
HashMap<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<>();
paramMap.put("llId", userId);

Map<String, Object> resultsetMap = simpleJdbcCall.execute(paramMap);

Map<String, Object> results = new HashMap<>();

Object result1 = resultsetMap.get("#result-set-1"));
Object result2 = resultsetMap.get("#result-set-2"));

System.out.println("Resultset-1-->" + result1);
System.out.println("Resultset-2-->" + result2);
```

In the above code gives multiple Resultsets, in every Resultset have key,value pairs

```
"result-set-1":[{ "key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]
```

and i want to get a Key&value from result-set-1(as individually)

Comment: To be clear, you have a PL/SQL function which returns some JSON? And what you want is for this function to return one KV pair instead of a collection? Or for your Java code to parse the result set and pick out the first pair?

Comment: from result-set-1 I need to take one Key and Value for some validation

Comment: in above code  is printing whole Object as result-set-1 but couldn't get key value pair from result set Object. Is there any alternate way for that?

Comment: @APC  any help? ....

Comment: sorry, I do PL/SQL but it seems like you need SpringBoot expertise.